# stop password textbox to be empty when click on button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, calendar, passwords

i have a user name, password and a calendar button which when click, a calendar appear and insert the date selected into the date textbox field, and a submit button.

After, i key in value for user name and password and click on the calendar button, the password textbox field because empty. So how can i going to stop the password textbox field to become empty when i click i the calendar button??

i set visible calendar only when click on the button

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Calendar>
```

is there a way?

Comment: How is clicking your calendar related to your password textbox?

Comment: back to 1995: use a font with same representation of each character (equivalent to *): `password.ttf`. Remove the TextMode=password attribute. You can also remove your password protection and check the ip address of the client computer. Don't forget to be compatible with IE4 also

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, ASP.Net clears a password textbox before sending it to the client. This happens for instance on a postback, after the click on that calendar has been processed.

Comment: You could use javascript to re-inject the value at the browser. Note that the reason for clearing is that else the clear-text password would be exposed. So do you really want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are clearing it on postback in the codebehind.  What does your PageLoad code look like?